# Is there another way to write Gasping and Panting sounds?

Tags: onomatopoeia, sounds

I'm making a comic where a character is scared and is hyperventilating. What should I write to make it as if they're panting/gasping?

Comment: ***Out of breath***: 
- Breathing with difficulty, panting, gasping. For example, After five flights of stairs I'm out of breath. 
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+breath

Comment: @Josh61: She wants onomatopoeic words for comics. Like BANG. or SNIKT.

Comment: @Trina: How about HUFF. It is a real word.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing "puff puff" used in that medium for that purpose. Are you looking for an alternative to that?

Comment: This is so much easier in Japanese... Manga has a wealth of lovely syllables to choose from :P

Answer (score 3):

Apart from *huff* and *puff* suggested in the comments:

[image]

You could also use:

**huh** and **phoo** (even thought dictionaries don't list this meaning for the first one, and don't list the second one at all, they sound pretty short-of-breathy):

[image]

Verbs such as: gasp, pant or *whiff* can be put into small clouds instead of onomatopoeia.

---

Images from:

http://magicalspacepony.com

http://adammurphy.com

Comment: I think the artist intends "huh" to be breathing in, and "phoo" to be breathing out.

Comment: @J.R. Now that you said it, it does make sense :-)